# Failed to Upgrade Nginx modules after upgrade Nginx to v1.22.0

Tags: nginx, centos7

I upgraded Nginx from 1.16 to 1.22.0 after that tried to upgrade modules but every attempt failed.

```
My OS="CentOS 7"
```

Nginx Modules that need to upgrade:

```
nginx-mod-http-image-filter.x86_64    1:1.16.1-1.el7                  @epel
nginx-mod-http-perl.x86_64            1:1.16.1-1.el7                  @epel
nginx-mod-http-xslt-filter.x86_64     1:1.16.1-1.el7                  @epel
nginx-mod-stream.x86_64               1:1.16.1-1.el7                  @epel
nginx-mod-mail.x86_64                 1:1.16.1-1.el7                  @epel
```

One of the available modules and it's info:

```
# yum info nginx-mod-stream

Installed Packages
Name        : nginx-mod-stream
Arch        : x86_64
Epoch       : 1
Version     : 1.16.1
Release     : 1.el7
Size        : 171 k
Repo        : installed
From repo   : epel
Summary     : Nginx stream modules
URL         : http://nginx.org/
License     : BSD
Description : Nginx stream modules.

Available Packages
Name        : nginx-mod-stream
Arch        : x86_64
Epoch       : 1
Version     : 1.20.1
Release     : 9.el7
Size        : 89 k
Repo        : epel/x86_64
Summary     : Nginx stream modules
URL         : https://nginx.org
License     : BSD
Description : Nginx stream modules.
```

One of my efforts:

```
# yum update nginx-mod-stream

ackage nginx-mod-stream.x86_64 1:1.20.1-9.el7 will be an update
--> Processing Dependency: nginx(abi) = 1.20.1 for package: 1:nginx-mod-stream-1.20.1-9.el7.x86_64
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: 1:nginx-mod-stream-1.20.1-9.el7.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: nginx(abi) = 1.20.1
           Available: 1:nginx-1.20.1-9.el7.x86_64 (epel)
               nginx(abi) = 1.20.1
           Installed: 1:nginx-1.22.0-1.el7.ngx.x86_64 (@nginx-stable)
               Not found
           Available: 1:nginx-1.8.0-1.el7.ngx.x86_64 (nginx-stable)
               Not found
           Available: 1:nginx-1.8.1-1.el7.ngx.x86_64 (nginx-stable)
               Not found
           Available: 1:nginx-1.9.0-1.el7.ngx.x86_64 (nginx-mainline)
...
...
```

So here's my question, How can I upgrade them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that your NGINX has been installed from the NGINX stable repository. From your output:

> Installed: 1:nginx-1.22.0-1.el7.ngx.x86_64 (@nginx-stable)

If you want to keep NGINX installed from that repo, the EPEL's packages are unnecessary (they don't do anything, because NGINX package from its official repository already includes stream module).

So all you have to do is `yum remove nginx-mod-*`

Comment: Thanks, How can I know Which repository is NGINX installed by(in both ubuntu and centos)?

Comment: @HassanYousefzadeh wouldn't know for ubuntu, but for CentOS it's `yum info nginx` where you can tell which repository it was installed from.